# Unity3D - Get Mathematical Plane from Primitive Plane in same world position

Tags: unity-game-engine, primitive, plane

I have a GameObject.Plane in a given position for visual purposes.
From that, given the plane's rotation and position in world space, I have to make a mathematical plane to use in the next calculations, but something's off.

I've tried doing

```
new Plane(go.transform.InverseTransformDirection(-go.transform.right), go.transform.InverseTransformPoint(go.transform.position));
```

where ***go*** is the primitive plane object.
Its position in world space seems fine, judging from the later results, but the rotation is not.

The Primitive plane(go) is rotated 90 degrees so instead of facing upwards it's facing the side.

What's going wrong here?

**Edit:** Current setup is

```
go.transform.InverseTransformDirection(-go.transform.right);
return new Plane(go.transform.up, go.transform.position);

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.magenta; 
    Gizmos.DrawLine(planePrimitive.transform.position, planePrimitive.transform.position + plane.normal * 3f);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```c#
go.transform.InverseTransformDirection(-go.transform.right)
```

returns a vector facing to the side and you are using it as the `Plane`'s `normal`.

---

A primitive `Plane` object's normal is simply it's local `transform.up` vector.

Then note that a `Plane` takes world space coordinates so it makes no sense to use `InverseTransformDirection` and `InverseTransformPoint` since `transform.up` and `transform.position` already are in world space.

```c#
new Plane(go.transform.up, go.transform.position);
```

---

If you are rather talking about a primitive `Quad` object then the vector you want is `-transform.forward` instead.

```c#
new Plane(-go.transform.forward, go.transform.position);
```

---

To your Gizmos:

You are using the `testPlane.normal` like it was a position. It is not! The normal is a direction and doesn't tell anything about the position.

What you want to do would be e.g. (without using local space gizmos)

```c#
Gizmos.DrawLine(go.transform.position, go.transform.position + testPlane.normal * 3f);
```

or if you can depend only on the plane itself use

```c#
Gizmos.DrawLine(plane.distance, plane.distance + testPlane.normal * 3f);
```

In this second plane the `plane.distance` is the vector from `0,0,0` to the closest point on the plane. It will therefore still not be exactly in the position of the given plane object.

Comment: Thank you. For clarification I am using a PrimitiveType.Plane. 
I am using a Gizmos line to show the normal of the mathematical plane, and it's facing in the right direction, although its position is offset from where it should be. So it's being interpreted as non-intersecting.
For reference, the primitive plane is nested in many other game objects which is located off the center, and it seems the mathematical plane is in the center (judging from the gizmos line position which could be wrong)

Comment: I don't see your Gizmos drawing ... the `Plane` is infinitely big since it is a pure mathematical construct .. it doesn't really have a "center" or "position" therefore I guess unity simply uses `0,0,0` ... You know however that you could also draw gizmos in [local Space](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos-matrix.html), right?

Comment: That localSpace Gizmos is awesome. Now it's actually drawing in the right place, using the primitive's position and the plane's normal as direction. Although the plane is still seen as non-intersecting somehow. Its position must be off?

Comment: Thanks, the Gizmos is fixed now. It's drawing from the center of the primitive plane, pointing in the right direction, no weird offsets. The (mathematical) plane is passed into a function that checks if it intersects with another mesh, and it says it does not.
It worked earlier by desperate attempts of changing some variables here and there, so I know it's not this function's fault. How come the plane isn't recognized in this position?